# How to view public miifoto log posts

Tags: miitomo

I want to know if you can and how to view public miifoto log posts or if they even are public

Answer (score 1):

I tested out this feature for myself to figure out how it worked and this is what I've found:

If you choose to share a Miifoto publicly to your Miifoto log, it will be available for all of your friends. To see your friends' public Miifoto logs, hit the "Miifoto Log" button then click on the "View Miifotos" button underneath any of your pictures. This will show you all of your friends' Miifotos. This is the **default** behavior if you are not connected to any social networking profiles.

If you *are* connected to a social network and you chose to post it to any of them, then a post will be made with the "#miifoto" hashtag for others to find easily. You can see the Twitter posts [here](https://mobile.twitter.com/search/live?q=%23Miifoto+since%3A2017-2-8). This was a link generated from the app itself by clicking the "Miifoto" button in the menu then clicking the "View Twitter" button at the top of the screen. This is how you can view others publicly posted Miifotos without being their friend.